# Could not find named connection string Server nhibernate MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

New to programming and getting this error.
I have no idea Please Help.
this is my save button click and my configuration file.

```
  private void save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Details d =new Details();
            d.Firstname = firstname.Text;

            Configuration cfg=new Configuration();

            cfg.Configure("NHibernate.xml");
            ISessionFactory sessionfactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
            ISession session = sessionfactory.OpenSession();
            ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();
            session.Save(d);
            tx.Commit();
  }
```

My Configuration File Nhibernate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration"
             type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler,NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">

  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">
      NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
      NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect,Nhibernate
    </property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string_name">
      Server=localhost;Database=mohit;User ID=root;Password=root
    </property>

    <mapping assembly="TestNhibernate"/>
  </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
please help
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either this **`name="connection.connection_string"`**:

```
<session-factory>
    ...
    <property name="connection.connection_string"> 
      Server=localhost;Database=mohit;User ID=root;Password=root
    </property>
```

Or the **`name="connection.connection_string_name"`** with the `<connectionStrings>` configuration:

```
// another web.config section "<connectionStrings>"
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MyName" 
    connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=mohit;User ID=root;Password=root" />
</connectionStrings>

// here we reference the name defined in the other section
<session-factory>
    ...
    <property name="connection.connection_string_name">MyName</property>
```